# get info about package update in openSuSE

Tags: package-management, opensuse, suse, patch, zypper

Is there any way to get information about an available package update via zypper?

I can get info about a patch with:

```
zypper info -t patch pachNameHere
```

and I can obtain the patch name via:

```
zypper list-patches
```

I want to do something similar with `zypper list-updates` to get info about those updates like release notes, bugfixes, etc in order to know how important they are.

I am also using the zypper nagios plugin (nagios-plugins-zypper)

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way I found is to use PackageKit CLI (`pkcon`). It's very usefull since it is used by other distros and can be a standarized way to query about software updates.

e.g.:

Get a list about all updates

```
pkcon get-updates
```

Then you can query updates about a specific package:

```
pkcon get-update-detail foo
```

e.g.:

```
pkcon get-update-detail udev
```

I am not using `zypper` but is been launched from command line so I can script it.
Also, there is a [nagios plugin using PackageKit](https://github.com/opinkerfi/nagios-plugins/tree/master/check_package_updates)